# Moving multiple objects with touch

Tags: objective-c, ios, touch, uilabel

I have an app where you have to move around different letters (in the form of `UILabels`) with touch. Since there are many different `UILabel` objects, I have tried creating this code, which prevents any labels sticking together:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView: self.view];


bool pickup = YES;


if (pickup) {

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(a.frame, touchPoint)) {

        a.center = touchPoint;

        pickup = NO;
    }
}

if (pickup) {

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(x.frame, touchPoint)) {

        x.center = touchPoint;
        pickup = NO;

    }

}

if (pickup) {

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(x2.frame, touchPoint)) {

        x2.center = touchPoint;
        pickup = NO;

    }

}
if (pickup) {

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(eq.frame, touchPoint)) {

        eq.center = touchPoint;
        pickup = NO;

    }

}        

if (pickup) {

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(b.frame, touchPoint)) {

        b.center = touchPoint;
        pickup = NO;

    }

}


}
```

But here are some problems:

1. Moving is not smooth, labels stop moving once my finger moves of the image (obviously because of `if (CGRectContainsPoint(a.frame, touchPoint))`
2. And also once I bypass a label while moving another label, my finger starts moving the label I bypassed

How can I do this, I know there is a better way then what I am doing right now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put it all in one chained animation `touchesMoved` is old school. Add a gesture recognizer on each of your label. then try this in that selector -

```
- (void)labelTouchSelector:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [gesture locationInView: self.view];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 
                          delay:0 
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                     animations:^(void) 
     {
         if(CGRectContainsPoint(a.frame, touchPoint))
         {
              a.center = touchPoint;
              pickup = NO;
         }
     } 
     completion:^(BOOL finished) 
     {
         if(finished)
         {
             //do some cleanup here
             pickup = NO;
         }
     }];
    return;
}
```

Comment: hmmm... when would I call this method and also, you cannot assign pickup in a block...

Comment: add this method as a selector in your gestureRecogniser that you assign to each of the UILabels.

Comment: Hmm... i have to take that back unfortunately... i left my old code back so that is why i thought it was working. NOthing is happening...

Answer (score 0):

I would try creating a new UILabel Class that would implement touchesBegan, touchesMoved, and touchesEnded. Put your relevant code in each of the methods. Create a method for this class that assigns a member the value of a letter. Instantiate each new object of this class in your ViewController and set its letter here along with other necessary details such as label.center.   I hope this helped.

Example from my code (which uses UIImage,you would need to find a way initialize the class with UILabel however the standard method goes about doing so):

```
@implementation myClass

- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    if (self = [super initWithImage:image])
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    return self;
}


-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
    pos = [touch locationInView: self];


    self.center = pos;


        NSLog(@"Touches Began Called.");

}


-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    activePoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];    

    int dx = self.center.x + (activePoint.x - pos.x); 
    int dy = self.center.y + (activePoint.y - pos.y);

    CGPoint newPoint = CGPointMake(dx,dy);
    self.center = newPoint;

        NSLog(@"Touches Moved Called.");


}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {



    NSLog(@"Touches Ended Called.");

}
```